# How to show results as a percentage with SQL?

Tags: sql, percentage

I am trying to complete some exercises where I must show how many products cost above 20 as a percentage of the total. I can easily show the products that cost above 20 but I am not sure how to answer the question as a percentage. The total amount of products is 77.

> 4. Display a table with (1) categoryname and (2) how many products in this category cost above 20 out of the total products in the category (in percentage).

I have written so far:

```
SELECT categoryname, price 
FROM [Products] 
WHERE price > 20
```

which tells me there are 37 records.

Comment: What DBMS are you using. It looks like SQL Server. Is that right?

Comment: this smells of homework.

Comment: @JNevill it is the online server example database I found through w3schools.

Comment: @Daniel A. White I am trying to teach myself so not homework.

Comment: Is that the full table structure of [Products]-  a table with two columns: categoryname and price?  Doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 3):

`Count` (and similar aggregate functions) ignore `null`s. You could use a `case` expression to nullify products that don't cost over 20 and count it, leaving you with a count of the products that cost more than 20. Dividing this count by the total count will give you a percentage:

```
SELECT   category, 100 * COUNT(CASE WHEN price > 20 THEN 1 END) / COUNT(*) AS percentage
FROM     products
GROUP BY category
```